# How to return SecondActivity values to state like it were in beginning

Tags: android, kotlin

I have SecondActitivity and when it starts I assign specific values: listTitle, dbJustForPlaing,currentCursorPosition, numberA and so on.

```
 class  SecondActivity : OptionMenuHelper() {
val listTitle: String by lazy { intent.getStringExtra(Values.listTitle) }
lateinit var dbJustForPlaing: DataBaseJustForPlaying
var currentCursorPosition: Int = -1
lateinit var cursorOfWholeList: Cursor
var lastCursorPosition: Int = -1
lateinit var oneRowCursor: Cursor
var numberA = 0
var numberB = 0

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_personal_test)

//some functions
}
}
```

During the use of this activity, variables are changing. Now I want to add button to SecondActivity, if user presses it, all variables must be returned to same state like they were when activity just started. What is the best way to do that?

I can do this:

```
            fun startNewActitivy(){
    val intent = Intent(this, SecondActitivity::class.java)
    intent.putExtra("listTitle", listTitle)
    startActivity(intent)
    finish
     }
```

But I am not sure if this is correct way to do. I need piece of code which will help to easy support my app in future and which also will be efficient in device resource consumption

Comment: Just create a function and assign the default values again. No need to recreate the activity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out by Peyman in the comments, just create a function that set's the default values for the variables. Something along the following lines,

```
fun setVariableDefaultValues() {
    currentCursorPosition = -1
    lastCursorPosition = -1
    numberA = 0
    numberB = 0
}
```

You can then call the `setVariableDefaultValues()` method anywhere you want to reset the values.